# Retrieving Firebase Data with Conditions?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

i want to retrieve data from my Prt Ss (image upload)

[image]

This problem is, how to get value from this child condition? (more user phone number) random phone number and push id?

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("Cart List").child("Admin View") ?
```

Comment: *i want to retrieve data from my Prt Ss*. What is the exact data you want to get? Add as a JSON file or again at least a screenshot.

Comment: If you know the user's phone number, use the phone number like `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Cart List").child("Admin View").child("111")` to get the list of products for that one phone number.


If you don't want to deal with push ids, then you may need to structure your tree differently, like using a HashMap: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to retrieve all products within the random phone numbers. You'll have to retrieve all phone numbers and then iterate through their children.

Something like this:

```
List<Phone> phones = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
.getReference().child("Cart List").child("Admin View");

for(Phone phone : phones) {
  Map<String, Products> values = phone.getValue();
  for(Map.Entry<String, Products> entry : phone.entrySet()) {
     Product product = entry.getValue();      
  }
}
```

Comment: This is very inefficient if you just want the products for only one phone number, which is what I think OP is asking for.

Comment: Yes, if he only one products for one phone there's no need for that but I understood that's what he wanted.
As you commented I think would be better if he re-structured the data.